# Ubuntu 9.10 Only Sees 244 MB RAM, while BIOS and Windows Sees 1.5 GB

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, memory, bios

I have 1.5 GB of RAM installed on an older Dell, Pentium 4.  I just installed Ubuntu 9.1 and the system is only seeing 244 MB of RAM, even though there is 1.5 GB on the system.  The BIOS sees all of it.  I ran a Knoppix disc and it only saw 25 MB upon booting.

I made no particular changes to the installation taht would affect this.  I looked through the BIOS and the only setting I could see was the AGP aperture.  Not even sure what this is.

Anyone know where I went wrong?

I also tried moving the memory modules around on the board.  Booted with the 1 GB stick, still saw 244 MB.

NOTE - This same system, except for the hard drive, had Windows XP running on it.  The user who ran it said that the RAM was good and always showed 1.5 GB.

Here is `sudo cat /proc/meminfo`

`MemTotal:         250064 kB`
`MemFree:            3832 kB`
`Buffers:           13356 kB`
`Cached:            52216 kB`
`SwapCached:        19676 kB`
`Active:            91504 kB`
`Inactive:         113884 kB`
`Active(anon):      60572 kB`
`Inactive(anon):    82156 kB`
`Active(file):      30932 kB`
`Inactive(file):    31728 kB`
`Unevictable:           0 kB`
`Mlocked:               0 kB`
`HighTotal:             0 kB`
`HighFree:              0 kB`
`LowTotal:         250064 kB`
`LowFree:            3832 kB`
`SwapTotal:       4883720 kB`
`SwapFree:        4781204 kB`
`Dirty:               496 kB`
`Writeback:           720 kB`
`AnonPages:        123796 kB`
`Mapped:            23368 kB`
`Slab:              17248 kB`
`SReclaimable:       7932 kB`
`SUnreclaim:         9316 kB`
`PageTables:         5304 kB`
`NFS_Unstable:          0 kB`
`Bounce:                0 kB`
`WritebackTmp:          0 kB`
`CommitLimit:     5008752 kB`
`Committed_AS:     740372 kB`
`VmallocTotal:     770600 kB`
`VmallocUsed:       26008 kB`
`VmallocChunk:     662544 kB`
`HugePages_Total:       0`
`HugePages_Free:        0`
`HugePages_Rsvd:        0`
`HugePages_Surp:        0`
`Hugepagesize:       4096 kB`
`DirectMap4k:      114128 kB`
`DirectMap4M:      147456 kB`

Hardware configuration:

- eMachine T3958
- Intel Celeron D 340, 3 GHz processor, Socket 478
- 1.5 GB RAM (one 1 GB and two 256 MB sticks)

I posted `dmesg` and `hwinfo --short` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wg0Gpt9Z).

**EDIT** - I found out some additional, rather important information just now.  My monitor configuration was such that, when I changed my monitor to the second channel of a 1>2 VGA splitter, I see additional information upon booting:

`Alert! OS install mode enabled.`
`Amount of available memory limited to 256MB.`

I'm not sure what this means or from where it originated.  Do I have a BIOS problem?

**EDIT** - So upon searching through the web and my BIOS, I found a setting in the BIOS called "Install Mode."  This was turned "on" for some reason.  Not sure if I did it or it changed as default when I installed the new hard disk.  Anyway, this was my problem the whole time.  Errgh.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: In system monitor under system and the fact that my system runs slow...

Comment: can you run this command and paste the output?

cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: yah, already ran it...  right at the top it reads MemtTotal 250064 kb.  I'm on another system right now, and that system is updating...  I will paste later.

Comment: That is very strange indeed. Have you tried running memtest from knoppix? Type "memtest" at the boot prompt instead of pressing enter to boot into the gui.

Comment: FYI - it's Ubuntu 9.10, not 9.1. The 9 represents 2009 and the 10 represents October.

Comment: Knoppix boot revealed the 255 MB total memory, but, no, I didn't run the `memtest` from Knoppix.  @MarkM, thx for the FYI, Ubuntu 9.10...

Comment: Can you post more details about your hardware? If it is reproducible between distros, it is a bug in kernel probably. Also, you can post `dmesg` output to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) -- that will help greatly.

Comment: I just made some edits to the question, as well as added the `dmesg` and `hwinfo --short` bits to pastebin.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Mode was set to "on" in the BIOS.  Either I changed it inadvertently or it defaulted when I installed a new hard disk.  Changed this back and it is seeing all the RAM.

Comment: Ah... this would fall into the category of 'Fix your BIOS' :)

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS RAM map is only telling Linux that there's only 256MB of memory available:

```
BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 00000000000a0000 (usable)    : 640k
BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000000ff74000 (usable)    : 260560k
BIOS-e820: 000000000ff74000 - 000000000ff76000 (ACPI NVS)
BIOS-e820: 000000000ff76000 - 000000000ff97000 (ACPI data)
BIOS-e820: 000000000ff97000 - 0000000010000000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec10000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000fecf0000 - 00000000fecf1000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000fed20000 - 00000000fed90000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee10000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000ffb00000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
```

Ideally, fix your BIOS. Or, try booting with `mem=1536m` specified as an additional kernel parameter. You may need to tweak it slightly - Linux will crash and burn if you specify more memory than available.

Comment: Why would the BIOS map tell me this, even though when I launch the BIOS with F2 on start-up, and scroll to memory, it shows all of it: 1536 MB ?  I will look into the kernel tweak...  How would I "fix" the BIOS?  Would this require updating the firmware (flashing it)?  Thanks.

Comment: I also found this quote from http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO.html#ss2.4 "In some cases, the memory reported via e820 can also be wrong, and so the mem=exactmap was added."  It looks like I can use `mem=1500m` and see what happens.  Literature says if I specify more memory than I have, bad things will happen.  What kind of things?  Can I reboot without the `mem=` parameter and get back to where I was?

Comment: The mem=???? parameter is one time only if you add it at the boot prompt. To make it permanent, add it to grub.conf or lilo.conf

Comment: Yes, got this eventually.  Thanks.  Did you see the other part of the question?  The last EDIT?  It seems something is preventing my system from using more than 256MB RAM.