# How To Boot with "mem=1024m" Argument using GRUB - Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: boot, memory, grub, command-line

I am still working on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/152481/ubuntu-9-10-only-sees-244-mb-ram-while-bios-and-windows-sees-1-5-gb). This new one is a different question so I thought it would be good to post a new question.  Is this the proper protocol or should I have just edited the other question?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with the kernel 2.6.32-22-generic on a Toshiba Satellite laptop.  When I enter the GRUB menu (I have Ubuntu 9.10 installed as well), I can choose which kernel to boot. I use scroll down to the one I want and press "e" and I expect to be able to enter `mem=1024m` and force the kernel to use this much memory. But when I run `cat /proc/meminfo` or look in the process manager after booting wth this argument I still see all the RAM:  ~2 GB.

Am I using this boot argument incorrectly? The boot configuration (before I add anything) looks like this:

```
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,1)
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 10270f21-1c42-494b-bd3f-813c23f6d\
518
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic root=UUID=10270f21-1c42-494b-b\
d3f-813c23f6d518 ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-22-generic
```

The way I did this was that I added the `mem=1024m` after the last line and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (Emacs save and boot the kernel) and the system booted.

I tried adding `mem=1024m` to the end and the beginning of this list and it appeared to not change the RAM allocation.

Comment: if you need to know how to add a command-line argument to your boot menu, that's appropriate for a separate question (although this is very likely a duplicate).  keep the memory troubleshooting stuff on your earlier question -- if you try something and it doesn't work, update *that* question, not this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Ubuntu and Debian-based installations that use Grub2, you shouldn't edit */boot/grub/grub.cfg* directly.  That file is configured by running the *update-grub* command, which happens automatically at various times (like when installing new kernel images).

Instead, you need to add kernel commandline options to the *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX* or *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT* variables in */etc/default/grub*:

```
# these options don't get added to recovery boot entry
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

# these options get added to both standard and recovery boot entries
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="var1 var2 mem=1024m"
```

Once you've finished editing, don't forget to generate a fresh Grub menu with the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg for more on how Debian/Ubuntu Grub configuration works.

Comment: Thanks to @quackquixote I've learnt another cryptic GRUB2 setting today :-)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the paramters go after the **linux** line:

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic root=UUID=10270f21-1c42-494b-b\
d3f-813c23f6d518 ro quiet splash`

So the new boot parameter line would be:

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic root=UUID=10270f21-1c42-494b-b\
d3f-813c23f6d518 ro quiet splash mem=1024m`

**EDIT** - I just looked over at Stack Overflow and found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).  I apologize for answering my own question.  I usually ask a question when I get stumped and then keep on working on it, so sometimes I figure it out before SU does.  I do not intend to do this for reputation.  It just happens sometimes.

Comment: if you change the *linux* commandline in your */boot/grub/grub.cfg* directly, it will work, but your changes will be overwritten the next time you update your kernel, or your grub installation, or install anything else that triggers *update-grub*.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be either:

```
mem=1024M
```

*(note the capital M? Or doesn't it matter?)*

or:

```
mem=1024mb
```

Just curious as I stumbled upon this post while researching ways to control the memory.

I've been using `mem=1024mb`, and adding the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mem=1024mb"
```

Then run:

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

These options get added to both standard and recovery boot entries:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="var1 var2 mem=1024m"
```

The correct usage of the above line is as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mem=1024MB"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).